# URLRequest - "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Error (Swift)

Tags: swift, httprequest, option-type

I am trying to perform an HTTP POST request in swift that will send some data to my server using PHP file, but it crashes with the error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The `token` and `selectedAreaNames` (the error is in the first line) are just regular strings. What could be the problem?

```
let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxxxx.xxx/register.php/\(token)|\ (selectedAreaNames)")! //error is here...
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("error: \(error)")
    } else {
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
        }
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("data: \(dataString)")
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: `url` is nil. It's invalid. Why? Maybe because your URL has some spaces or other invalid characters that need to be percent escaped. Plenty of question about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that’s really how your URL must look, you can do:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxxxx.xxx/register.php")!
    .appendingPathComponent(token + "|" + selectedAreasNames)
```

That will percent escape those portions of the URL (including the `|`).

---

That having been said, this is an exceedingly unusual format for a `POST` request, which usually has the data being posted inside the body of the request, not just added as another path component of the URL. And if this was a `GET` request, where the parameters are added to the URL, you’d generally see this after a `?` in the URL, separating the path of the request from the query. And this structure of simply `TOKEN|VALUES` is an unusual query structure, too.